# Must declare the scalar variable "@postScript"

Tags: variables, declare, scalar

We have been using the following code on all of our SQL versions and SQL 2016 SP3 seams to break it.

I use this in a stored procedure as one of the variables provided.
,@PostScript nvarchar(max)= NULL
IF @postScript IS NOT NULL  --Must declare the scalar variable "@postScript".
EXEC (@postScript) --Must declare the scalar variable "@postScript".

The following lines also error with having to declare the scalar variable.
EXEC sp_executesql @postScript

Testing the code the following also causes the same issue:

declare @PostScript nvarchar(max)
set @PostScript = null
IF @postScript IS NOT NULL -- Must declare the scalar variable "@postScript".
select @PostScript

Is this a bug in the SQL 2016 SP3 or do I need to code things differently?

Comment: Are the variable names case sensitive?

Comment: Thanks it was a case issue. 
case-insensitive, accent-sensitive, Kana-sensitive, and width-sensitive